# asp.net MVC parameter always gets default value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Consider this controller action:

```
public ActionResult List(int userid = 0)
{
    var campaigns = db.Dyn_Campaigns.Where(c => c.UserID == userid);
    return View(campaigns.ToList());
}
```

UserID field in the model is a int.

This is the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<KnockoutExample.Models.Dyn_Campaigns>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
 }

<h2>List</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateCreation)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CompanyID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserID)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descr)
    </th>
    ...
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreation)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descr)
    </td>
    ...
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

And this is my custom routing in global.asax:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{userid}",
  new { controller = "Campaigns", action = "List", userid = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The problem is that the `userid` parameter always get the default value (0).
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How can we tell why controller method is always getting a default value when we can't see your client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your registerRoutes as follows

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{userid}",
                    new { controller = "Campaigns", action = "List", userid = UrlParameter.Optional });    

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
                );


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

cause the `UrlParameter.Optional` is not a int. `userid` must to be a int otherwise it doesn't find userid.
For example:
In your controleur:

```
public ActionResult List(int userid = 0)
{
...
}
```

In your model (for example)

```
Myclass{
    int id;
}
```

In your view:

```
 @model MyApp.Model.MyClass
 ...
    new { controller = "Campaigns", action = "List", userid =  model.id});
```

In Asp.net MVC 4, the parameter in your view and your controleur must be the same type and name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I didn't understood what is `model.id` and where you put the `int id;` declaration.

Comment: where this should be: `new { controller = "Campaigns", action = "List", userid =  model.id});` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well changing the parameter from:

```
public ActionResult List(int userid = 0)
```

To:

```
public ActionResult List(int id)
```

solved the issue. but I still don't understand why the method does not accept a parameter of the same type but with different name.

The RouteConfig looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{userid}",
            new { controller = "Campaigns", action = "List", userid = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

Comment: so the problem looks like that your custome route doesn't gets hit. route with id param was hit. Show your route.config

Comment: Try to move myroute above teh default route

Answer (score -1):

because userid is getting 0 as a parameter if it is missing it should be nullable

```
 public ActionResult List(int? userid)
{
var campaigns = db.Dyn_Campaigns.Where(c => c.UserID == userid);
return View(campaigns.ToList());
}
```

Edit based on your Edit

you are passing the parameter name id, it should be userid

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { userid=item.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { userid=item.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { userid=item.ID })
```

Comment: It is not missing. I'm sending the parameter. that is the problem.